# MPIO on Win Server 2k16 w/ EMC Unity

Tags: windows, storage-area-network, dell, unity

I have two Dell R630's running Windows Server 2016, slated to be Hyper-V hosts but not yet clustered, attached to an EMC Unity array via fibre channel through a pair of Brocade 300 SAN switches. The switches are zoned properly - I can see the initiator WWN's of the R630 FC adapters in Unisphere and I'm able to configure the hosts there with no problem. Unisphere shows both hosts up and all initiators up with paths to both SP modules. All initiators show as logged in. A LUN has been created and presented to both hosts.

On both Windows hosts, however, the LUN is not present in disk management and no devices are listed in the "Discover Multi-Paths" tab of the MPIO GUI. Running a 'mpclaim -e' comes back with "There is no enterprise storage connected on the system", even though the Unity can see the HBAs with no problems, the storage has been presented to the hosts, and all initiators are logged in. Drivers for the FC adapters are installed and working normally.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Besides the driver, is there a separate MPIO utility from EMC that can/should be installed? I've seen that on SANs before.

Comment: There's PowerPath - but the thing is, MPIO (or lack of it) shouldn't have any bearing on the LUN showing up as a disk in disk management. MPIO would prevent Windows from seeing each path to the LUN as a separate instance of the same disk - but the disk should show up regardless. Something else is preventing discovery of the LUN I think.

Answer (score 0):

FYI -

Fiigured I'd do a quick test to rule out the fully booted Windows environment as the source of the problem. So I launched into the Windows pre-boot installation environment and, unsurprisingly, the Unity LUN was instantiated and I was able to see all four instances of the disk there (one instance per path). I went ahead and reinstalled Windows Server on both hosts from scratch and I'm now able to see the LUN in disk management as well.

I'm at a loss as to what was preventing Windows from discovering the LUN, though guess it's kind of moot at this point.